# How to deal with many-to-many relationships in the general repository, unit of work pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-2.0, unit-of-work

For my thesis I decided to create something in MVC and to challenge myself I added a DAL and BL layer. I created "services" in BL that allow me to work with my Entities.

I am really wondering if I understood the pattern correctly, because I am having issues dealing with many-to-many relationships - and especially how to use them properly.

This is my current implementation (simplified, to get the general idea):

**PersonService**: this class is my abstraction for using my entities (I have several entity factories as well). Whenever I need to add a Person to my DB, I use my service. I just noticed that mPersonRepository should probably be named differently.

```
public class PersonService : IService<Person> {
    private UnitOfWork mPersonRepository;
    public PersonService() => mPersonRepository = new UnitOfWork();

    public void Add(Person aPerson) {
        mPersonRepository.PersonRepository.Insert(aPerson);
        mPersonRepository.Safe();
    }

    public void Delete(Guid aGuid) {
        mPersonRepository.PersonRepository.Delete(aGuid);
        mPersonRepository.Safe();
    }

    public Person Find(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> aFilter = null) {
        var lPerson = mPersonRepository.PersonRepository.Get(aFilter).FirstOrDefault();
        return lPerson;
    }

    public void Update(Person aPerson) {
        mPersonRepository.PersonRepository.Update(aPerson);
        mPersonRepository.Safe();
    }
}

public interface IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
    void Add(TEntity aEntity);
    void Update(TEntity aEntity);
    void Delete(Guid aGuid);
    TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> aExpression);
    TEntity FindByOid(Guid aGuid);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> aExpression);
    int Count();
}
```

**UnitOfWork**: pretty much similar as the way Microsoft implemented it.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {

    private readonly DbContextOptions<PMDContext> mDbContextOptions = new DbContextOptions<PMDContext>();
    public PMDContext mContext;
    public UnitOfWork() => mContext = new PMDContext(mDbContextOptions);
    public void Safe() => mContext.SaveChanges();

    private bool mDisposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool aDisposed) {
        if (!mDisposed)
            if (aDisposed) mContext.Dispose();
        mDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private GenericRepository<Person> mPersonRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Project> mProjectRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Person> PersonRepository => mPersonRepository ?? new GenericRepository<Person>(mContext);
    public GenericRepository<Project> ProjectRepository => mProjectRepository ?? new GenericRepository<Project>(mContext);
```

**GenericRepository**: just as before, it is very similar.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
    internal PMDContext mContext;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> mDbSet;

    public GenericRepository(PMDContext aContext) {
        mContext = aContext;
        mDbSet = aContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> aFilter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> aOrderBy = null,
        string aProperties = "") {
        var lQuery = (IQueryable<TEntity>)mDbSet;

        if (aFilter != null) lQuery = lQuery.Where(aFilter);

        foreach (var lProperty in aProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) {
            lQuery = lQuery.Include(lProperty);
        }

        return aOrderBy != null ? aOrderBy(lQuery).ToList() : lQuery.ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(object aId) => mDbSet.Find(aId);
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity aEntity) => mDbSet.Add(aEntity);

    public virtual void Delete(object aId) {
        var lEntity = mDbSet.Find(aId);
        Delete(lEntity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity aEntity) {
        if (mContext.Entry(aEntity).State == EntityState.Detached) mDbSet.Attach(aEntity);
        mDbSet.Remove(aEntity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity aEntity) {
        mDbSet.Attach(aEntity);
        mContext.Entry(aEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

**PMDContext**: an implementation of DbContext.

```
public class PMDContext : DbContext {
    public PMDContext(DbContextOptions<PMDContext> aOptions) : base(aOptions) { }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder aOptions) {
        if (!aOptions.IsConfigured) aOptions.UseSqlServer("<snip>");
    }
}
```

**Entities**

```
public class Person {
    public Person(<args>) {}

    public Guid Oid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Project {
    public Project(<args>) {}

    public Guid Oid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use it all like the following:

```
var lPerson = Factory.CreatePerson(<args>);
var lPersonService = new PersonService();
lPersonService.Add(lPerson);
<..do some work..>
lPersonService.Update(lPerson)
```

Now I do not need to worry about calling Safe, or whatever. It works just fine, but now I ran into an issue: how do I deal with many-to-many relations in my Entities. For example my Person can have multiple Projects and my Project can have multiple Persons.

I updated my PMDContext to get a link table:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder aModelBuilder) {
        aModelBuilder.Entity<PersonProject>().HasKey(x => new { x.PersonOid, x.ProjectOid });
    }
```

**Link table**

```
public class PersonProject {
    public Guid PersonOid { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectOid { get; set; }
}
```

And updated both my entities with the following property.

```
public ICollection<PersonProject> PersonProjects { get; } = new List<PersonProject>();
```

Now I am confused on how to use my linked table. I thought I could follow a similar approach like this:

```
var lPerson = PersonService.FindByOid(aPersonOid);
var lProject = ProjectService.FindByOid(aProjectOid);

var lPersonProject = new PersonProject() { PersonOid = aPersonOid,
    ProjectOid = aProjectOid };

lPerson.PersonProjects.Add(lPersonProject);
lProject.PersonProjects.Add(lPersonProject);

PersonService.Update(lPerson);
ProjectService.Update(lProject);
```

But this ends up not doing anything to the PersonProject table in my DB. My guess is that I lack the code to actually write to that table, since I do not have a PersonProject service that handles this. I am confused.

How would I advance using my current approach, or what do I have to change? I am only a beginner w/ entity frameworks and already happy I got this far.

Any input is appreciated especially on the services -> pattern implementation. I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really using a service layer pattern. Your "service" is just a repository, which then uses your unit of work to access another repository. In short, you've got multiple layers of meaningless abstraction here, which will absolutely *kill* you in an app you have to maintain for any amount of time.

In general, you should *not* use the unit of work / repository patterns with ORMs like Entity Framework. The reason why is simple: these ORMs *already* implement these patterns. In the case of EF, the `DbContext` is your unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

If you're going to use something like Entity Framework, my best advice is to *just use it*. Reference it in your app, inject your context into your controllers and such, and actually use the EF API to do the things you need to do. Isn't this creating a tight coupling? Yes. Yes it is. However, the point so many miss (even myself for a long time) is that coupling is *already* there. Even if you abstract *everything*, you're still dealing with a particular domain that you can never fully abstract. If you change your database, that *will* bubble up to your application at some point, even if it's DTOs you're changing instead of entities. And, of course you'll still have to change those entities as well. The layers just add more maintenance and entropy to your application, which is actually the antithesis of the "clean code" architecture abstractions are supposed to be about.

But what if you need to switch out EF with something else? Won't you have to rewrite a bunch of code? Well, yeah. However, that pretty much never happens. Making a choice on something like an ORM has enough momentum that you're not likely to be able to reverse that course no matter what you do, regardless of how many layers of abstractions you use. It's simply going to require too much time and effort and will never be a business priority. And, importantly, a bunch of code will have to be rewritten regardless. It's only a matter of what layer it's going to be done in.

Now, all that said, there is value in certain patterns like CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation), which is an abstraction (and not a meaningless one, that). However, that only makes sense in large projects or domains where you need clear cut separation between things like reads and writes and/or event sourcings (which goes naturally with CQRS). It's overkill for the majority of applications.

What I would recommend beyond anything else if you want to abstract EF from your main application is to actually create microservices. These microservices are basically just little APIs (though they don't *have* to be) that deal with just a single unit of functionality for your application. Your application, then, makes requests or otherwise access the microservices to get the data it needs. The microservice would just use EF directly, while the application would have no dependency on EF at all (the holy grail developers think they want).

With a microservice architecture, you can actually check all the boxes you think this faux abstraction is getting you. Want to switch out EF with something else? No problem. Since each microservice only works with a limited subset of the domain, there's not a ton of code typically. Even using EF directly, it would be relatively trivial to rewrite those portions. Better yet, each microservice is completely independent, so you can switch EF out on one, but continue using EF on another. Everything keeps working and the application couldn't care less. This gives you the ability to handle migrations over time and at a pace that is manageable.

Long and short, don't over-engineer. That's the bane of even developers who've been in the business for a while, but especially of new developers, fresh out of the gates with visions of code patterns dancing in their heads. Remember that the patterns are there as *recommended* ways to solve *specific* problems. First, you need to ensure that you actually have the problem, then you need to focus on whether that pattern is *actually* the best way to solve that problem *your specific circumstance*. This is a skill - one you'll learn over time. The best way to get there is to start small. Build the bare minimum functionality in the most straight-forward way possible. Then, refactor. Test, profile, throw it to the wolves and drag back the blood-soaked remains. Then, refactor. Eventually, you might end up implementing all kinds of different layers and patterns, but you also might not. It's those "might not" times that matter, because in those cases, you've got simple, effortlessly maintainable code that just works and that didn't waste a ton of development time.

Comment: You are right. I over-engineered the hell out of this. I was doing similar things like our company does, but never really realized the fact that my application is nowhere near the complexity they offer.

I will start over with less abstractions and then we will see if I can get further than where I ended up now.